# why doesn't boost asio async write detect that socket has been closed?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I am in early stages of building and testing a TCP socket client with boost asio. What I noticed is that if the boost socket make a connection to the server, if I shut down the server while it's connected (to test how boost responds to a closed connection), and then write a message to the server using async_write, nothing happens at all. The async write handler method is never called (I would have thought it would be called with an error). (The async write handler method is called correctly if the socket does not get disconnected.)

**UPDATE**

After adding a deadline_timer to check whether it is timing out before the async write handler is 
called, I now am getting an error in the write handler method.  It Seems like somehow having the deadline_timer also using the thread of the io_service is now letting the error bubble up to the handler method. I can't explain this yet...

The code looks like this:

```
comm_mgr(server_info& info, io_service& service): server_info_(info), io_service_(service), timer_(service) 
{
    DEBUG("comm_mgr.ctor()");           
}

void start(void)
{
    DEBUG("start(): starting connect() method call...");
    connect();
    DEBUG("start(): starting thread to run io_service::run()");
    t_ = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&io_service::run, &io_service_));

    timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&comm_mgr::check_write_timeout, this));
}

void connect()
{

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    tcp::resolver::query query(server_info_.host, server_info_.port);
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    INFO("connect(): resetting socket and calling async_connect with handle_connect callback. connecting to: " << server_info_.host << ":" << server_info_.port);
    socket.reset(new tcp::socket(io_service_));
    socket->async_connect(*iterator, boost::bind(&comm_mgr::handle_connect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++iterator));

}

void send(EZXMsg& msg)
{
    const char* encoded = msg.api_msg(0);
    size_t bytes = std::strlen(encoded);
    timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(30));
    boost::asio::async_write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(encoded, bytes), boost::bind(&comm_mgr::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));     
}

void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    if (!error)
    {
       LOG4CXX_DEBUG(logger, "handle_write(): sent bytes" << bytes_transferred);
    } else {
       LOG4CXX_ERROR(logger, "handle_write(): error. ex=" << error);
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the write method register any error when writing while the socket is closed?

Comment: Is the server shutdown gracefully ? Because you will have entirely different behaviour depending on how this is done. If you kill the server, then its socket is gone of course, but the client does not know about it because it never received a FIN to indicate the the socket is closed. On top of this, if you do receive a FIN, or the peer indicates that its closed its socket, this will tell you that it will not send anymore. This is called a half close. This does not mean that you cannot send anymore. The way to detect that it closed its socket is by receiving, not by sending at all.

Comment: your client should receive a `PIPE` signal, unless you have installed a signal handler. In which case your `async_write` handler will be invoked with a [`broken_pipe`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/error__basic_errors.html) error. Do you have a signal handler installed?

Comment: @SamMiller:  I don't have a signal handler installed. (Didn't know there was such a thing...)  It sounds like that might be necessary. Do you have a link to where docs show how to set this?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck: Philip, server is shut down with SIGTERM, which allows it to exit cleanly.  Note that the server is a Java app. I don't see any reaction in the boost client when server is shut down. The boost client is waiting on async read (and write) to complete.  I would have thought at least one would get EOF or some error.

Comment: @Sam assuming a POSIX operating system, read the man pages: `man 7 signal` and more specifically, [`man 2 sigaction`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction). I suggest you edit your question to include more of your client code, something that we can [compile and test](http://sscce.org) ourselves.

Comment: @SamMiller: I looked at trying to post my code, but it has too many dependencies to post simply/cleanly. However, running the boost chat-client and chat-server example code, shows same behavior.  If you kill the server, the client blithely continues without any awareness of an error. (It never completes any async method after server is killed.)

Comment: Maybe a simpler approach is to use a dead_line_timer to make sure any async operation gets handled (completed) within some finite period of time?

Comment: What OS are you seeing this behavior on?

Comment: Well, on my windows 7 box, I modified the ASIO example to print a message when it closes the socket in the client (the `do_close` function).  As soon as a close the server, the `handle_read` is called with an error which closes the client socket.  All further writes appear to just be silently dropped.

Comment: @DaveS: Thanks Dave - I made that change as you said, and I also see the ASIO example printing a message in the do_close method. I'll check my code further.

Comment: @DaveS: You identified the problem - the socket close *was* detected in the read_async handler, but I didn't put anything in the code to respond to an error, and close the socket. Therefore the write didn't see that the socket was closed when it went to write.  Interestingly, enough, however, adding the timer somehow also caused the error to bubble into the async write handler (which it didn't before).